# Very simple GtkGLArea example using Glade

Tags: c, opengl, gtk, gtk3, glade

I can't find very simple GtkGLArea drawing example which draw lines and rectangles. All examples, which I find, are too complicated, not written in C and impossible to compile (because of outdated libraries/packages). I have managed to successfully compile glarea (https://github.com/ebassi/glarea-example), however, it is too complex to understand how it works. Could anybody can finish code below, so program draws simple line or rectangle?

I have prepared very simple project, which contains window with GtkGLArea.

P.S. I am aware of Cairo, but it is too slow for my purpose. 20% cpu usage only to draw simple grid is not ok.

This simple project contains 3 files:

compile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# Šis ir Testa programmas kompilēšanas un palaišanas skripts

echo "Program started to compile"
gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0 gio-2.0 epoxy` -rdynamic -o './Test.run' './Test.c' `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0 gio-2.0 epoxy`
echo ""

echo "Program should start now"
'./Test.run'
echo ""

echo "End of script"
```

GUI_design.glade

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_main">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="default_width">1920</property>
    <property name="default_height">1080</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_main_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <placeholder/>
    </child>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkDrawingArea">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Test.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#include <epoxy/gl.h> //This will be needed for OpenGL

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkBuilder      *builder; 
    GtkWidget       *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    builder = gtk_builder_new();
    gtk_builder_add_from_file (builder, "GUI_design.glade", NULL);

    window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window_main"));
    gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);

    g_object_unref(builder);

    gtk_widget_show(window);                
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}

// called when window is closed
void on_window_main_destroy()
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}
```

To compile and run the program, place all 3 files in one folder and run compile.sh

Comment: Did you give a look at the example in [`gtk3-demo`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/master/demos/gtk-demo/glarea.c) (sample program shipped with GTK+)? Also, don't expect people to write code for you, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service. We can help but won't do the work for you.

Comment: The link you posted, explained [here](https://www.bassi.io/articles/2015/02/17/using-opengl-with-gtk/)